# Can not commit to SVN (Path ... already exists)

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu, pycharm, webdav

I installed subversion on an ubuntu server following this guide (I only use svn through webdav) : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion

I created some repositories and initialized them with initial structure (branches/tags/trnuk).

Then I started working with my python code (using PyCharm), after 2 commits I could not commit anymore, each time I want to commit now it says :

```
svn: E175005: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175005: Path '/svn/backend/trunk/libs' already exists
```

And this happens with any repository (even new ones) and the files and directories are new and never existed before (I even tried to create new project but same thing happens), I am stuck, anyone has an idea of what is happening ?

**EDIT**

I created the the libs directory using the command (in the server):

```
svn mkdir  file:///home/svn/backend/trunk/libs -m "Libs" --parents
```

Everything went fine :

> Committed revision 2.

But when I wanted to commit a file from Pycharm into directory libs, I got:

```
svn: E160007: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160007: No such transaction ''
svn: E175002: MERGE of '/svn/backend/trunk/libs': 500 Internal Server Error
```

I checked the Apache logs in the server, this is what is in it:

```
[Wed May 21 18:30:51.930864 2014] [dav:error] [pid 17997] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:35834] Could not MERGE resource "/svn/backend/!svn/act/0ada9e1f-4601-0010-b475-91cd296adad5" into "/svn/backend/trunk/libs".  [500, #0]
[Wed May 21 18:30:51.930904 2014] [dav:error] [pid 17997] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:35834] The transaction specified by the activity does not exist  [500, #160007]
[Wed May 21 18:30:51.930908 2014] [dav:error] [pid 17997] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:35834] No such transaction ''  [500, #160007]
```

Thanks again for your help

**EDIT 2**

I forgot to mention that SVN updates from PyCharm seems to work perfectly.

**EDIT 3**

Just tried committing from Netbeans, and it works perfectly, so this seems a PyCharm issue, I will keep investigating

Comment: PyCharm is trying to recommit the directory, the question is why. Can you view the `svn status` of what PyCharm thinks it's going to do? If it's trying to add the directory again, revert that change and try again.

Comment: Tried to commit from Netbeans, it works perfect! what is wrong with PyCharm ? :|

Comment: It's confused. ;) Are you sure PyCharm is working with the right checkout?

Comment: Yes it is.
This is not the first time I work with PyCharm, I have been using it for more than a year and it always worked perfectly with SVN, but now ... it is really weird

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the same error message trying to import a directory into a repo.
After a while, I noticed that I was trying to import a symlink, instead of the actual directory. Replacing the symlink with the actual directory fixed the issue.
Check that you are not trying to commit a symlink

Comment: Thank you for your answer (even if this question is old now), but no I wasn't trying to commit a symlink